# Delete from database via ViewList MultiSelection

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I have the next code.

```
public class ListAnotaciones extends ListActivity {

AnotacionesOpenHelper openHelper = AnotacionesOpenHelper.getAnotaciones(this);
SQLiteDatabase bd;
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bd = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from anotaciones", null);
    final ArrayList<Cursor> lista = new ArrayList<Cursor>();

    try {
        String [] from = {"titulo", "fecha"};
        int [] to = {R.id.anotacionesTexto, R.id.anotacionesFecha};
        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.anotacion, cursor, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(
                new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                        int seleccion = getListView().getCheckedItemCount();
                        boolean borrado = false;

                        if(checked){
                            lista.add((Cursor)getListView().getItemAtPosition(position));
                            lista.get(0).moveToFirst();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lista.get(0).getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            /*
                            SQLiteCursor seleccionado = (SQLiteCursor)getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                            for(int i = 0;i < lista.size();i++){
                                if(lista.get(i).getString(0).equals(seleccionado.getString(0))){
                                    lista.remove(i);
                                    borrado = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            */
                        }
                        mode.setTitle(seleccion + " Notas Seleccionadas");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ctx_borrar,menu); //Inflamos el menú creado como XML en Menu
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.CtxLblBorrar:
                                /*
                                for(int i = 0 ; i < lista.size();i++){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lista.get(i).getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    bd.delete("anotaciones","_id = " + lista.get(i).getString(0),null);
                                }
                                */
                                while(lista.get(0).moveToNext()){
                                    bd.delete("anotaciones","_id = " + lista.get(0).getString(0),null);
                                }
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

                    }
                }
        );
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.anotaciones, menu);

    return true;
}*/

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.CtxLblBorrar:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se ha pulsado Borrar - " + getListView().getCheckedItemCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OPCION NO PROGRAMADA",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_borrar, menu);
}
}
```

I'm trying to delete from the database and then update the ListView. I've seen several solutions here but I can't adapt the solutions to my code (I'm pretty new with android). 
More specifically, I don't know how to "save" the options than I need to delete.
If you need more code please say so.

Comment: Just i don't know how to delete properly. I know the theory "Delete from database and then refresh the screen", but i can delete, but i can't know how to save the multi selection for then delete.

Comment: You can save position on onItemCheckedStateChanged().

Comment: Yes but, then, what can i know what is the exact key for delete from de DB. i need to pass a parameter in db.delete()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
I'm so sorry, I'm a little blind,
It's the code for my question

```
public class ListAnotaciones extends ListActivity {

AnotacionesOpenHelper openHelper = AnotacionesOpenHelper.getAnotaciones(this);
SQLiteDatabase bd;
Cursor cursor;
Context contexto = this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bd = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from anotaciones", null);
    final ArrayList<Long> borrar = new ArrayList<Long>();
    try {
        String [] from = {"titulo", "fecha", "texto"};
        int [] to = {R.id.anotacionesTitulo, R.id.anotacionesFecha,R.id.anotacionesTexto};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.anotacion, cursor, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(
                new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Long.toString(id),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(checked){
                            borrar.add(id);
                        }else{
                            for(int i = 0; i < borrar.size();i++){
                                if(borrar.get(i) == id){
                                    borrar.remove(i);
                                }
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deseleccionado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ctx_borrar,menu); //Inflamos el menú creado como XML en Menu
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.CtxLblBorrar:
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se ha pulsado Borrar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                for(int i = 0 ; i < borrar.size();i++){
                                    bd.delete("anotaciones","_id=" + borrar.get(i),null);
                                }
                               return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.anotaciones, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Thanks you anyway for the solves